# If $T$ is a compact operator and $S$ is a bounded operator then $TS-ST$ cannot be the identity operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $T:L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1]$ be a compact linear operator and $S:L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1]$ be a bounded linear operator.
> Prove $$TS-ST \neq e$$ where $e$ is the identity operator.

My solution.

I am aware of the fact that if $T$ is compact and $S$ is bounded then both $TS$ and $ST$ are compact.
I am also aware of the fact that the sum of compact operators is compact, hence $TS-ST$ is compact.

However I know that the identity operator is not compact in infinite dimensional spaces, therefore $TS-ST$ cannot be equal to $e$ since one is compact and other is not.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: As Kavi said, your proof is correct. Some genaralisations can be fond here: https://books.google.de/books?id=ZEP1CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=Theorem+of+Wintner+Wielandt&source=bl&ots=5HZ8uV4II2&sig=ACfU3U07Kec84vai2EzAiNpVZrmO8u4mrg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4rM_73tn3AhWBwQIHHY2sA-0Q6AF6BAgYEAM#v=onepage&q=Theorem%20of%20Wintner%20Wielandt&f=false

Comment: For bounded operators the equality $ST-TS=I$ cannot happen as $\sigma(ST)\cup \{0\}=\sigma(TS)\cup \{0\}.$